# Get the contents of a line by line number in perl, awk, grep

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I would like to know if it's possible to get contents of line by line number as input. For example how can I get the contents of line 314 using a tool such as `perl`, `grep`, `awk`.

I have few options I have tried

1. Counting till the line number in `perl` and printing - not the most efficient
2. If I know the pattern in the line find line number using `grep -in "pattern" file`.

But something like vim `:314` is what I'm expecting using `perl`, `awk`, `grep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to print a single line given a line number With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==314' file
```

If you file is large you may want to quit after reaching the line:

```
$ awk 'NR==314{print;exit}' file
```

---

You could also use `sed` for this:

```
$ sed '314!d' file
```

Equally:

```
$ sed -n '314p' file
```

With `sed` to print a line by number and quit you would do:

```
$ sed -n '314{p;q}' file
```

---

The `perl` solution will be similar to the `awk` solution however I don't know/use `perl` myself. This can not be done with `grep` unless you use `nl` or `cat -n` firts. However you can print the line numbers of lines matching the given pattern with `grep` using the `-n` option.

From `man grep`:

```
-n, --line-number                                  (-n is specified by POSIX.)  
Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.
```

Comment: @Raghav great, remember to upvote all useful answers and accept the most useful answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: I've never seen `quit` in `awk`. I know `exit` offers the same functionality.

Comment: @jaypalsingh I meant `exit`. I do this quit frequently as it's perfectly valid *(I shoudl say perfectly useless as it does nothing!)*.

Comment: gawk (other awks too?) handle undefined variables  as the empty string or zero (depending on the context). You sometimes see people ask here "I have {print $foo} but it prints the whole line!"

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, but evidently BSD/Mac awk doesn't accept undefined variables as the only expression in a statement.

Comment: I would always suggest getting `GNU awk` unless you don't have control over the software you can install on the machine.

Comment: Actually a Perl one-liner could emulate either Awk or Sed. Perl was designed to incorporate features of both languages. Perl comes with utilities to convert from [Awk](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html "perldoc a2p") and [Sed](http://perldoc.perl.org/s2p.html "perldoc s2p").

Comment: Actually? What and who are you referring to @BradGilbert? Nobody has said anything to the contrary.

Comment: You stated in your answer "*The perl solution will be similar to the awk solution ...*" When in actuality the Perl solution could have code that resembles both Awk and Sed, in the same solution. file` While you were right that the simplest Perl solution is more similar to Awk `perl -ne 'if( $. == 314 ){ print; last }'` if the question was about a range of lines, the simplest would be more similar to Sed. `sed -n '3,5{p};9{p}' file` => `perl -ne 'if(3..5 or $. == 9){print}'`

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne 'print if $. == 314' input
```

Comment: `perl -ne '(print),last if $. == 314' input` or `perl -ne 'if($. == 314){print;last}' input`

Answer (score 1):

P ossible solution as Perl-oneliner to read filename.txt and print out line n (starting with 0!):

```
perl -e 'my @lines= do { local(*ARGV); @ARGV="/path/filename.txt"; <> }; print $lines[n]'
```

A shorter one unsing special variable `$.` (starting with 1):

```
perl -ne 'print if $. == n' filename.txt
```

Comment: Good one. I did not think the @lines as an array which I could index. but for large files, I think this takes too much array / time .. I will use this for small files .. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MTie::File -we'use Tie::File; tie my @file, "Tie::File", $ARGV[0], autochomp=>0 or die "Error opening $ARGV[0]"; print $file[313]' /path/filename.txt
```

or using coreutils:

```
head -n 314 /path/filename.txt | tail -n 1
```